# How to do a 9-way Multi-way ANOVA without interaction effects?

Tags: anova

I am doing FEM simulations, where I am changing 8 material parameters, each with 9 levels. I have used a Taguchi L81 array to do the simulations, and now I'm trying to determine which parameters are significant. For that, I would like to use multi-way ANOVA, but all I can find are ANOVAs where the interaction of different parameters is also considered and I am not interested in that. Basically I would like to do a 9-way ANOVA without repetition as I am using one single index (dependent variable) to compare analysis results to a real-life experiment (each simulation results in one number as output).

Does such ANOVA even exist in practice and does someone have any reference to it? Can I perhaps just expand the equations for a two-way ANOVA without repetition to suit 8 parameters with 9 levels and expect any relevant results? Any help would be greatly appreciated as till now I have only worked with simple one-way ANOVA.

**EDIT:**

Working with expanded basic two-way ANOVA equations (suppose we have parameters $A$ and $B$) namely $SS_A = n\cdot b\cdot \sum \dots$, where $n=1$ because there is no replication, for an N-way ANOVA (parameters $A$, $B$, $C$ etc.) this equation, I assume, would become $SS_A=n\cdot \left(\prod_{i=1, i\neq A}^{N} m_i\right)\cdot \sum \dots$ where $m_i$ is the number of levels of $i$-th factor. This results in very big $SS_i$ numbers compared to calculated $SS_{total}$, which in turn means that $SS_{within}$ following the equation $SS_{total}=\sum_{i=1}^N SS_i+SS_{within}$ becomes **negative**. Accordingly, $MS_{within}$ and all the $F$-values also become negative. Of course, one could in the end just say that we treat negative $F$-values in their absolute form, but somehow it doesn't feel right. What is the solution?

Comment: Sorry, but this can't happen. You've done something wrong somewhere. These are sums of squares. They are always positive (well, I guess one could be 0, but that would be very odd).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing particularly difficult in a 9 way ANOVA that isn't difficult in a 2 way ANOVA, you just add more independent variables. You usually don't hear about 9-way because people simply use the term ANOVA. Or they use linear regression, which is the same model.

The general form is:
$$
Y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + \dots+ b_px_p + e
$$

All you've done is say $p = 9$.

Comment: This is great news, thank you. Forgive my boldness but I have a follow-up question because I have already implemented the equations in Python. I edited my original post due to character count.